# converting dictionary into dataframe as expected output in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, data-science

let's say i have a dictionary as

```
dj=  {
        "totalrecords": 2,
        "data": [
            {
                "stateCd": "U.K",
                "stateName": "uttarakhand",
                "details": {
                    "id": [
                        "2312-k",
                        "2312-k"
                    ],
                    "date": [
                        "10-OCT-2019",
                        "11-OCT-2019"
                    ],
                    "icp": [
                        2233,
                        6443
                    ],
                    "icpr": [
                        3.434,
                        23.232
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "stateCd": "U.P",
                "stateName": "uttar pradesh",
                "details": {
                    "id": [
                        "2712-k",
                        "5412-k"
                    ],
                    "date": [
                        "10-OCT-2019",
                        "11-OCT-2019"
                    ],
                    "icp": [
                        2233,
                        6443
                    ],
                    "icpr": [
                        32.434,
                        31.232
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    }
```

I want to convert this json/dictionary into data frame which would be like this using python:

[image]

but I am having no clue how to perform this action

i have also tried `pandas.json_normalize()`
but didn't get my expected column in output i.e. date,icp,icpr

```
data_trunc=dj['data']
pd.json_normalize(data_trunc,record_path=['details','id'],meta=['stateCd','stateName'])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8UDw.png)

Comment: You listed `pandas` as one of your tags, can you show us what you have tried? If you have no idea how to start, perhaps you can look at a tutorial first for converting dict to dataframe, e.g. https://datatofish.com/dictionary-to-dataframe/

Comment: what i have tried                                                                                                           print(response)
print(type(response))
dict_trunc = response['data'][0]
new = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_trunc)
print(new)

Comment: along with it i have also tried "flatten-json" but it didn't get the expeted output

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

[Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

```py
data = [{'state': 'Florida',
             'shortname': 'FL',
             'info': {'governor': 'Rick Scott'},
             'counties': [{'name': 'Dade', 'population': 12345},
                                {'name': 'Broward', 'population': 40000},
                                {'name': 'Palm Beach', 'population': 60000}]},
            {'state': 'Ohio',
             'shortname': 'OH',
             'info': {'governor': 'John Kasich'},
             'counties': [{'name': 'Summit', 'population': 1234},
                                {'name': 'Cuyahoga', 'population': 1337}]}]
result = pd.json_normalize(data, 'counties', ['state', 'shortname',
                                               ['info', 'governor']])
```

Output:

```
0        Dade       12345   Florida    FL    Rick Scott
1     Broward       40000   Florida    FL    Rick Scott
2  Palm Beach       60000   Florida    FL    Rick Scott
3      Summit        1234   Ohio       OH    John Kasich
4    Cuyahoga        1337   Ohio       OH    John Kasich
```

Comment: This is very nice! Pandas is useful. From only 1 line of code you did it wow! I was not knowing anything about pandas

Comment: Checkout panda’s related articles from [realpython](https://realpython.com/). There must be other better resources to learn pandas. This is the one I used

Comment: @SomeshwaranS i have tried pandas.json_normalize()  as pd.json_normalize(data_trunc,record_path=['details','id'],meta=['stateCd','stateName']) but didn't get my expected output can you pls help into this

Comment: Is it possible to edit the `details` object to a list of dict like `details = [{'id': '2312-k','icp':'2233','icpr':'3.434','date':'10-OCT-2019'},{{'id': '2312-k','icp':'6443','icpr':'23.232','date':'11-OCT-2019'}]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:-

```py
import json

f = open('1.json')
file = json.load(f)

for data in file['data']:
  stCd = data['stateCd']
  stateN = data['stateName']
  date = data['details']['date']
  icp = data['details']['icp']
  icpr = data['details']['icpr']
  full = f"StCd    StateName       Date          ICP          ICPR"
  whole = f"{stCd}     {stateN}    {date[0]}    {icp[0]}      {icpr[0]}"
  whole2 = f"{stCd}     {stateN}    {date[1]}    {icp[1]}      {icpr[1]}"
  print()
  print(full)
  print(whole)
  print(whole2)
```

Output:-

```
StCd    StateName       Date          ICP          ICPR
U.K     uttarakhand    10-OCT-2019    2233      3.434
U.K     uttarakhand    11-OCT-2019    6443      23.232

StCd    StateName       Date          ICP          ICPR
U.P     uttar pradesh    10-OCT-2019    2233      32.434
U.P     uttar pradesh    11-OCT-2019    6443      31.232
```